# Postfix non privileged docker image

Tags: docker, postfix, kubernetes

We are trying to create a docker image for postfix similar to [this one here](https://hub.docker.com/r/juanluisbaptiste/postfix). Later we want to use it as part of a kubernetes deployment. Therefore the container needs to run as a non-root user (rootless).

Has anybody managed to develop an image with postfix running as non-root user ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.